# How to declare an array of mutable strings with ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I want to invoke a C function from Python, and pass it a structure containing an array of mutable strings.

The C function is supposed to write its results into the array.

However, y Python program crashes before invoking the C function.

Here is a minimal example to reproduce the issue:

```
from ctypes import *

LINE_COUNT = 100
MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 30

class ExchangeStructure(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("results", LINE_COUNT * POINTER(c_char * MAX_LINE_LENGTH))]


def createExchangeStructure():
    exchange_structure = ExchangeStructure()
    results = []
    for i in range(LINE_COUNT):
        results.append(create_string_buffer(MAX_LINE_LENGTH))

    results_as_C_array = (LINE_COUNT * (c_char * MAX_LINE_LENGTH))(*results)

    exchange_structure.results = pointer(results_as_C_array)

def main():
    createExchangeStructure()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The C structure looks like this:

```
struct Response {
    ...
    char* results[LINE_COUNT];
    ...
};
```

It crashes at the last line of the function createExchangeStructure, with the following error message:

```
TypeError: incompatible types, LP_c_char_Array_30_Array_100 instance instead of LP_c_char_Array_30_Array_100 instance
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: Do you want your struct to have an array of pointers to `char` strings or the array of strings itself? Please show the C definition of `ExchangeStructure`.

Comment: I updated the question to include an extract of the C structure

Comment: You need pointers to 100 30-byte arrays. You can allocate those as one 2D block with 3000 bytes, and iterate over the rows to create a pointer to each row. This will be simpler if you change struct definition to use `POINTER(c_char) * LINE_COUNT`. Then you can assign the pointers using `exchange_structure.results[:] = ((c_char * MAX_LINE_LENGTH) * LINE_COUNT)()`. Note how each `POINTER(c_char)` supports assigning a char array to it, which is actually assigning a pointer to the first element.

Comment: If you want,  you can keep it as pointers to arrays, but you'll need a list comprehension to create the pointers, e.g. `exchange_structure.results[:] = [pointer(row) for row in ((c_char * MAX_LINE_LENGTH) * LINE_COUNT)()]`.